# How to get the image click on Froala Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, editor, froala

I want to get the `.click` of the image on ***Froala Editor*** to create a customize function, for that I want to get the image I have selected in the ***Froala Editor***.

I have Tried a couple of methods for this.

> 1.froalaEditor.click function:

```
$('#froala_editor').on('froalaEditor.click', function(e, editor, clickEvent) {
     console.log(clickEvent.toElement);
});
```

> 2.Custome jQuery function

```
$.extend({
    IFRAME: function (s) {
       var $t = $('.campaign-create-sec').find('iframe');
       if (typeof s !== 'undefined') {
             return $t.contents().find(s);
          }
             return $t;
    }
});

$('#froala_editor').on('froalaEditor.initialized', function (e, editor) {
    $.IFRAME('body').on('click', function (e) {
         console.log(e.target);
    });
});
```

In the above, both cases I am getting all the other elements other than `<img>` and `<video>` of what I tested, so Is there any other way for me to get the *click even for an image in Froala Editor*.

*A **[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jithinrajpr7/294t6vno/)** for you to check*, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a call back for an "after media add or something like this. Than you could add the click handler directly to the element after it was loaded into the editor

Comment: @SimonFranzen There is no such events in *Froala Editor*

Comment: You should open an Issue for this for the froala project

Comment: @SimonFranzen there is one https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/issues/101, but they have closed it by saying *find a JS outside of the editor*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var monitor = setInterval(function(){
     var iframe_found = $('iframe').length;
     console.log('iframe_found '+iframe_found);
     if (iframe_found) {
         clearInterval(monitor);
         $('iframe').contents().find("img").click(function(){
           $(this).css('border','2px solid #090');
           console.log('got that!');
         });
      }
   }, 100);
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/294t6vno/73/).

**setInterval()** : For checking `iframe` presence after page load. `iframe` may only load after the page data is loaded & in your case its from a editor plugin, may take some time surly to load.

`$('iframe').length;` : Confirms presence of `iframe`.

**clearInterval()** : For destroying the `setInterval()`, so avoids multiple checking again for `iframe`.

And, at last we are finding required `img` tag.

Try... Have a nice day.

Comment: Now I feel like dumb, I tried many other ways but never thought like this, because I was getting all other elements in the iframe other than the image. your answer worked well for me. ty so much. :)